# Insert a User Control within an ASP:Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I need to insert a user control into a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAdditionalPages">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="<%# ((ftj.com.AdditionalPageForProductDetail)Container.DataItem).DivID %>" class="tab_content">
                    <h1><%# ((ftj.com.AdditionalPageForProductDetail)Container.DataItem).Title %></h1>
                    <%# ((ftj.com.AdditionalPageForProductDetail)Container.DataItem).Body %>
                    <uc:EnrollmentMethod ID="EnrollmentMethod2" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>                    
        </asp:Repeater>
```

When the user control is inserted with this method the code behind cannot find EnrollmentMethod2.  Is it possible to add user controls in repeaters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find it because it's nested in the repeater. You will need to dig into the repeater to find it.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
    EnrollmentMethod control = (EnrollmentMethod )item.FindControl("EnrollmentMethod2");
}
```

Comment: I have attempted this and there is nothing in the Items or Controls collection.  Any hints?

Comment: At what point are you trying to access the controls? If there's nothing in the Items collection, that would mean one of two things: a) the items haven't been bound to the repeater yet, or b) the repeater was bound, but the data source was empty.

Comment: I needed to do this when I bound the item.  Thanks for the help.